# 401k vs. Vanguard ETF vs. Pay off home loan

Tags: etf

All -

I am wondering what is the best way to utilize my monthly savings. I have a large home loan at a 3.25% interest rate.

Should I take my savings and pay off the home loan or invest it elsewhere like Vanguard ETFs or stocks?

Comment: The title question asks about 401(k). Are you currently depositing to that account? Is there a company match, and if so, do you deposit to get the full match? The current accepted answer is fine, but the question can use more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 3.25% is a quite low borrowing rate, you are likely to do better over the long term by investing your savings. If your additional 401k contributions would receive a match, that makes it a no-brainer (but I'd guess you're already contributing enough to max out the match). Even without a match, or even without a tax-advantaged savings vehicle, you can likely earn more than 3.25% by taking some modest investment risk.

Answer (score -2):

The critical issue is, does your home loan still have the scam **PMI** attached?

That typically overwhelms all other factors.

If you are still under PMI, put everything in to reducing your mortgage until that is eliminated, forget everything else.

Comment: What is PMI? How do I find out if I am still under PMI?

Comment: @user855  PMI is private mortgage insurance. You have this if your down payment was below 20%. PMI is not fire insurance, it is to protect the lender if you default,

Comment: ok, I don't have PMI then

Comment: @user855- good news then

Comment: hi @JohnFx ...  help me understand why you edited out the adjective "scam" on PMI from my post?

Comment: Should they make a different choice if they are paying for non-scam PMI on their loan, as opposed to scam PMI?

Comment: @yoozer8 - PMI is just a scam. It's a marketing language scam. PMI is simply **a (much, much) higher rate**, for certain customers, disguised in absurd language.

Comment: @Fattie while PMI is definitely something you should avoid if at all possible, it's certainly not a *scam*.

Comment: @Fattie Because I was trying to keep your answer to factual claims and by cutting out the personal opinion on PMI from the answer. It is definitely not a scam, even if it is something you want to avoid paying. You get exactly what you pay for, there is no deception involved.

Comment: @JohnFx - hmm, you're stating that "You happen to believe PMI is not a scam."  You're wrong (as I explain a few comments above - it would be eliminated as incredibly deceptive marketing, to the point of only being describable as "a scam", in any other industry), but, you can see my rhetorical point, I'm not going to go through your posts and insert "which is a scam" each time I see you mention PMI, and then state to you in a comment "PMI is definitely a scam". I appreciate that basically ranters on the site need to be, well, silenced (I do so constantly :) ) but it's a fine line you know?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion, and your answer was pretty good when you stick to the facts and got my upvote. If you'd prefer to leave it in that's fine, but I'm changing to a downvote because the answer now feels more like a rant than a factual response.

Comment: That's surely my point, @JohnFx !  It is a matter of opinion.  I appreciate you voting your conscience and the input  :) PMI is just another "absurdly high-fees banking scam" writ large, and I'm confident expressing unpopular opinions against the government-banking sector, in spite of downvotes on a web site  :)